# NLog.Targets.Seq and composite formatting

Tags: nlog, datalust-seq

I'm using NLog and Seq together quite successfully, but a third-party library we use makes extensive use of [Composite Formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting) with message strings like:

```
"Updated counter via {0} - new value is {1}"
```

With the NLog.Target.Seq library, this is displayed without performing the replacements of the values intended by the third-party author.  When structured logging is used, everything works as expected.

There doesn't seem to be a way to override the layout for the SeqTarget class? Does anyone know how to force the SeqTarget to resolve this sort of message formatting?

Thank you!

Comment: See also: https://github.com/datalust/nlog-targets-seq/issues/67

Comment: Try updating to NLog.Targets.Seq v3.1.0 - https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Targets.Seq/3.1.0